# Realm Inherit base model in other models

Tags: javascript, react-native, mobile, realm

So I have read the doc but it didn't help,
What I have is a base model which has some common fields and I want to inherit those in all my other models.

**My Base Model**

```
class Base { }

Base.schema = {
  name: 'Base',
  properties: {
    uuid: { type: 'string', optional: false },
    created_by: { type: 'string', optional: false },
 }
}
```

**My Other Model:**

```
class Student { }

Student.schema = {
  name: 'Student',
  properties: {
    name: { type: 'string', optional: false },
    age: { type: 'int', optional: true }
    ...
  }
};
```

**Result I am expecting:**

```
{
  uuid: 'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx'
  created_by: 'xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx-xxx'
  name: 'Smith'
  age: 20
  ...
}
```

Comment: Currently, Realm JS doesn't support inheritance. I see that you have create an issue for it (https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/1839) - thanks!

Comment: ok @geisshirt thanks